# Updating a Page after Binding Data to it in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

we have code that is getting data from the server,the data is unzipped and parsed then the name of the files along with the icons related to them are supposed to be displayed on the UI, we are using a listbox and trying bind these 2 elements to the listbox, the data is getting bound but we are not able to update the page after binding.`

```
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
     <Image Source="{Binding Icon, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
<TextBlock Padding="10" Text="{Binding Widget, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>`
```

Comment: How do you bind in XAML? Get us a portion of xaml where you declare the ListBoxItemTemplate.

Comment: <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Image Source="{Binding Icon, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBlock Padding="10" Text="{Binding Widget, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

Comment: i am receiving an array of names and icons.. so how do we implement INotifyPropertyChanged am are very very new to WP7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that:

1. UIManager class is set as a dataContext for your XAML control.
2. UIManager has to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) in order to notify the UI that the collection you are binding to has changed (has some items added to it in your case).
3. Most important - use Output windows to locate all XAML binding issues.

   class UIManager: INotifyPropertyChaged
   {

   ```
   private ObservableCollection<ItemsList> _displayItem;

       public ObservableCollection<ItemsList> DisplayItem
       {
          get
          {
             return _displayItem;
          }
          set
          {
             if(value != _displayItem)
             {
                _displayItem=value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DisplayItem");
             }
          }

       public UIManager()
       {
          DisplayItem = new ObservableCollection<ItemsList>();
          DisplayCat(DataManager.getInstance().displayName, DataManager.getInstance().icons);
       }

       public void DisplayCat(string[] DisplayNames, BitmapImage[] Icon)
       {
               ObservableCollection<ItemsList> tmpColl = new ObservableCollection<ItemsList>();        

       for (int i = 0; i < DataManager.getInstance().count; i++)
           {
                   tmpColl.Add(new ItemsList { Widget = DisplayNames[i], Icon = Icon[i] });
           }
       DisplayItem = tmpColl;
       }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
   {
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
           {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
           }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: i am receiving an array of names and icons.. so how do we implement INotifyPropertyChanged am are very very new to WP7.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you how to do it. The formatting is almost fine.

Comment: so when something is added to the list box the Notifyrpopertchanged event should be triggered and the condition if(propertychanged!=Null) should become true and whatever is inside the if condition must be executed right?

Comment: and should i have to add anything in app.xaml.cs? coz i have added something thr.. i.e.,  public static UIManager UISettings
        {
            get
            {
                // Delay creation of the view model until necessary  
                if (UImanaged == null)
                    UImanaged = new UIManager();
                    return UImanaged;
            }
        }

Comment: this isnt working too :( the count of the entries is getting incremented to the no. of items added but the handler is still null so it isn't working ..

Comment: Aproova, you won't be able to successfully create an application if you use MVVM pattern without knowing of how it works. Read on MVVM and things will clear out for you.